# Can I be sure that a Sharepoint site is owned by the company?

Tags: security, sharepoint, phishing

I got an email at work asking me to update a password in a document at a web address in the form https://companyname.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/...

Can I be assured that the company "companyname" owns that Sharepoint site? Or could anyone have set up an account at Microsoft with that name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the company "companyname" owns the site and you just need to use your company email id to access.

Answer (score 0):

[https://companyname.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/…](https://companyname.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/%E2%80%A6)

We call "companyname" a domain name, and the domain name adopts the first-come, first-served principle and will not be repeated. belongs to your company.

Comment: I think it would be a subdomain in the case, the domain name is sharepoint.com, which is owned by Microsoft. They hand out subdomains to their users, but the question is would they do any kind of verification.

Comment: Please don't beg for votes here - the community prefers organic voting.